# Linux becomes very slow

Tags: kali-linux

I use Kali Linux since my first pc and the first version I used version **2017.1** and later updated to **2017.2**, then I switched to **2018.3** . That's where I found that my system was getting sluggish. I have done everything to fix it: I installed the latest version **2018.4** is the disaster, I formatted my disk and reinstalled version **2017.2** but nothing changes.

The cursor stops from time to time when I seize and this during 5 or 6 seconds, when I try to close a document or a web page it takes 5 or 6 seconds before closing, when I scroll the scroll bar in a site it takes 5 seconds or more before moving; In short, everything I try to do takes time before executing.

What should I do? Where can the problem come from? of my computer? or the system? do I have to reinstall the 2016.2 version of my system?

My computer is a fujitsu series with 8GB of RAM and 500GB of hard disk with intel core i5 processor.

Comment: I use kali come versatile system for almost 3 years and it is quite recently that this problem appears

Comment: This may be the first kali related question that has some validity.

Comment: any harware problems in log ? strange noise ? those symptoms are those before my windows broke down on disk fault.

Answer (score 1):

**If** you have totally wiped hard-disks and re-installed the some old OS (that worked before). Then all that is left is hardware (as all software was wiped).  A common fault is dust in the fans, causing an over heat.

However this is not the place to get hardware advice. (Though it is the place to ask the question, that leads to that answer.)

I would double check, by trying a live Debian USB/CD. If that does not work, then get some hardware advice.